# Separate mesh by loose parts in threejs

Tags: three.js, blender, mesh

I’ve created a some basic model in Blender. It’s 4 times subdivided cube (I need faces to look like squares), then faces was split by edges (in Blender too). Then I need to separate final mesh by loose parts in threejs (if I do that in Blender the exported file is too big, like a few MB big). So each face become separate one.

How should I do that?

#### Step 1 (blender)

[image: split faces by edges]

#### Step 2 (blender)

[image: separate by loose parts]

#### After step 2 each face is a separate mesh. I need to replicate step 2 in ThreeJS.

[image: each face become a separate mesh]

#### As a result I need to explode faces of a sphere

[image]

#### Here's what I have so far

[image]

I'll need much more faces to achieve the desired result. One possible solution would be to place 2 spheres one inside another and then "explode" them simultaneosly. But I need faces to be much smaller too.

My "explosion" code is heavily based on this: https://github.com/akella/ExplodingObjects/blob/0ed8d2668e3fe9913133382bb139c73b9d554494/src/egg.js#L178

And here's demo:
https://tympanus.net/Development/ExplodingObjects/index-heart.html

Comment: Would be great to provide an explanatory pictures of what you've got and the desired result, and the code of what you've tried.

Comment: thx for the tip, I've added a lot more info to the question

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Each quad is a mesh, so the more meshes you have, the greater drop of performance you get.

Comment: I made something similar to akella's work once: https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/xowRxE

Comment: yeah, my example is very similar, just faces instead of "pieces"  but the more separate pieces/faces you need, the bigger model size will be.  Model size with 1500 separate faces as meshes is 1300Kb already and I need about 10000 of them. Particle system won't work as I can't rotate individual particles and it won't look realistic without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would use bufferGeometry.

According to this showcase: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry
16000 triangles are generated with normal orientations.
I think you should use BufferGeometry.

Build on top of your codePen,
Here you'll find a solution to have quad faces (instead of your triangles) oriented along a sphere surface.

The core to get the quad faces laying along the surface of a sphere:

```js
for (let down = 0; down < segmentsDown; ++down) {
      const v0 = down / segmentsDown;
      const v1 = (down + 1) / segmentsDown;
      const lat0 = (v0 - 0.5) * Math.PI;
      const lat1 = (v1 - 0.5) * Math.PI;

      for (let across = 0; across < segmentsAround; ++across) {
        //for each quad we randomize the radius 
        const radius = radiusOfSphere + Math.random()*1.5*radiusOfSphere;
        const u0 = across / segmentsAround;
        const u1 = (across + 1) / segmentsAround;
        const long0 = u0 * Math.PI * 2;
        const long1 = u1 * Math.PI * 2;
        //for each quad you have 2 triangles
        //first triangle of the quad
        //getPoint() returns xyz coord in vector3  array with (latitude longitude radius) input
        positions.push(...getPoint(lat0, long0, radius));
        positions.push(...getPoint(lat1, long0, radius));
        positions.push(...getPoint(lat0, long1, radius));
        //second triangle of the quad. Order matter for UV mapping,
        positions.push(...getPoint(lat1, long0, radius));
        positions.push(...getPoint(lat1, long1, radius));
        positions.push(...getPoint(lat0, long1, radius));
      }
    }
```

https://codepen.io/mquantin/pen/mdqmwMa

I hope this will do the job for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I was thinking about BufferGeometry but it seems that it's more complicated than I've thought. I'm not much into math, that's why I preferred to make model in blender.

Looking at exanple from threejs website I've managed to create a sphere from triangles, but have very little understanding on how to make planes instead or how to rotate them to they cover the sphere.  Here's what I have so far: https://codepen.io/olhapi/pen/xxPqKjd?editors=0010

Comment: Hi @OlegVdovenko, I edited my answer to help you acording to your comment.  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey @mquantin! Thank you very much for your help and example, it helped a LOT. Here's my almost final animated sphere: https://codepen.io/olhapi/pen/vYWrXMK?editors=0010
One last question: how can I rotate each "plane" individually? I've found some vertex rotating function, but it looks like planes just floating on the sphere, instead of rotating along their own origin (not sure if I described that right).